# JavaFX editable cell with focus change to different populated cell

Tags: javafx, tableview, cell, edit, tablecell

I need editable cells for JavaFX TableView.  The default TextFieldTableCell requires the user to press enter to commit a change.  I think a typical user expects the change to be kept when clicking outside the cell.  All the features I want include:

1. Single-click selects the cell and
2. Another single-click on a cell, in the selected cell, or enter press, starts editing.
3. A double-click on a cell starts editing.
4. Pressing enter commits the changes to the cell
5. Changing mouse focus anywhere outside the cell commits the changes to the cell

I found a EditCell version in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28456215/tableview-edit-focused-cell) 
It fulfills the first 4 requirements and partially the 5th, but when the user clicks on another populated cell in the table the edit changes are lost.  The focus listener is triggered, but no commit.  Clicking on an empty cell or another scene element commits the changes.

There is a supposedly a solution provided in [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24694616/how-to-enable-commit-on-focuslost-for-tableview-treetableview/25291137#25291137)
However, the solution only contains snippets of code instead of a working example.  I was not able to implement it.

Can anyone help put the pieces together and demo a class than extends TableCell that has all the features I listed above?

Answer (score 3):

I'm probably a little late to this party but here goes.

Not being able to commit the value of the changed cell is probably due to the default implementation of the commitEdit method in TableCell, as it treats a loss of focus as a cancel-action by default.

However, user James_D created a nice workaround [here](https://gist.github.com/james-d/be5bbd6255a4640a5357)

EDIT:

Example class based on James_D's work

```
import java.util.function.Function;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.StringConverter;


public class TableViewCommitOnFocusLoss extends Application {


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        TableView<Person> table = new TableView<>();

        table.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
        table.setEditable(true);

        table.getColumns().add(createColumn("First Name", Person::firstNameProperty));
        table.getColumns().add(createColumn("Last Name", Person::lastNameProperty));
        table.getColumns().add(createColumn("Email", Person::emailProperty));

        table.getItems().addAll(
                new Person("Jacob", "Smith", "jacob.smith@example.com"),
                new Person("Isabella", "Johnson", "isabella.johnson@example.com"),
                new Person("Ethan", "Williams", "ethan.williams@example.com"),
                new Person("Emma", "Jones", "emma.jones@example.com"),
                new Person("Michael", "Brown", "michael.brown@example.com")
        );

        Button showDataButton = new Button("Debug data");
        showDataButton.setOnAction(event -> table.getItems().stream()
                .map(p -> String.format("%s %s", p.getFirstName(), p.getLastName()))
                .forEach(System.out::println));

        Scene scene = new Scene(new BorderPane(table, null, null, showDataButton, null), 880, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private <T> TableColumn<T, String> createColumn(String title, Function<T, StringProperty> property) {
        TableColumn<T, String> col = new TableColumn<>(title);
        col.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> property.apply(cellData.getValue()));

        col.setCellFactory(column -> EditCell.createStringEditCell());
        return col ;
    }

    public static class Person {
        private final StringProperty firstName = new SimpleStringProperty();
        private final StringProperty lastName = new SimpleStringProperty();
        private final StringProperty email = new SimpleStringProperty();

        public Person(String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
            setFirstName(firstName);
            setLastName(lastName);
            setEmail(email);
        }

        public final StringProperty firstNameProperty() {
            return this.firstName;
        }

        public final java.lang.String getFirstName() {
            return this.firstNameProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setFirstName(final java.lang.String firstName) {
            this.firstNameProperty().set(firstName);
        }

        public final StringProperty lastNameProperty() {
            return this.lastName;
        }

        public final java.lang.String getLastName() {
            return this.lastNameProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setLastName(final java.lang.String lastName) {
            this.lastNameProperty().set(lastName);
        }

        public final StringProperty emailProperty() {
            return this.email;
        }

        public final java.lang.String getEmail() {
            return this.emailProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setEmail(final java.lang.String email) {
            this.emailProperty().set(email);
        }


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}

class EditCell<S, T> extends TableCell<S, T> {

    // Text field for editing
    // TODO: allow this to be a plugable control.
    private final TextField textField = new TextField();

    // Converter for converting the text in the text field to the user type, and vice-versa:
    private final StringConverter<T> converter ;

    public EditCell(StringConverter<T> converter) {
        this.converter = converter ;

        itemProperty().addListener((obx, oldItem, newItem) -> {
            if (newItem == null) {
                setText(null);
            } else {
                setText(converter.toString(newItem));
            }
        });
        setGraphic(textField);
        setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);

        textField.setOnAction(evt -> {
            commitEdit(this.converter.fromString(textField.getText()));
        });
        textField.focusedProperty().addListener((obs, wasFocused, isNowFocused) -> {
            if (! isNowFocused) {
                commitEdit(this.converter.fromString(textField.getText()));
            }
        });
        textField.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, event -> {
            if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.ESCAPE) {
                textField.setText(converter.toString(getItem()));
                cancelEdit();
                event.consume();
            } else if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.RIGHT) {
                getTableView().getSelectionModel().selectRightCell();
                event.consume();
            } else if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.LEFT) {
                getTableView().getSelectionModel().selectLeftCell();
                event.consume();
            } else if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.UP) {
                getTableView().getSelectionModel().selectAboveCell();
                event.consume();
            } else if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.DOWN) {
                getTableView().getSelectionModel().selectBelowCell();
                event.consume();
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Convenience converter that does nothing (converts Strings to themselves and vice-versa...).
     */
    public static final StringConverter<String> IDENTITY_CONVERTER = new StringConverter<String>() {

        @Override
        public String toString(String object) {
            return object;
        }

        @Override
        public String fromString(String string) {
            return string;
        }

    };

    /**
     * Convenience method for creating an EditCell for a String value.
     * @return
     */
    public static <S> EditCell<S, String> createStringEditCell() {
        return new EditCell<S, String>(IDENTITY_CONVERTER);
    }


    // set the text of the text field and display the graphic
    @Override
    public void startEdit() {
        super.startEdit();
        textField.setText(converter.toString(getItem()));
        setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
        textField.requestFocus();
    }

    // revert to text display
    @Override
    public void cancelEdit() {
        super.cancelEdit();
        setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);
    }

    // commits the edit. Update property if possible and revert to text display
    @Override
    public void commitEdit(T item) {

        // This block is necessary to support commit on losing focus, because the baked-in mechanism
        // sets our editing state to false before we can intercept the loss of focus.
        // The default commitEdit(...) method simply bails if we are not editing...
        if (! isEditing() && ! item.equals(getItem())) {
            TableView<S> table = getTableView();
            if (table != null) {
                TableColumn<S, T> column = getTableColumn();
                TableColumn.CellEditEvent<S, T> event = new TableColumn.CellEditEvent<>(table,
                        new TablePosition<S,T>(table, getIndex(), column),
                        TableColumn.editCommitEvent(), item);
                Event.fireEvent(column, event);
            }
        }

        super.commitEdit(item);

        setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);
    }

}
```

Comment: Please post solutions inside the original SO post. Links are useful but are not considered an answer.

Comment: Here's this fix for `TreeTableCell`: https://gist.github.com/egphilippov/a6cb5566b4603093e123b02bb785e7ac and https://gist.github.com/egphilippov/c5155ee84760b680c30725937df68f20 .